# React pagination component search issue

Tags: reactjs

Having issues with my search.

for some reason I have an error saying

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```
const maxPages = Math.floor(movies.length / PAGE_SIZE);
```

Any help much apreciated.
[Demo here](https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/dyRvvWB?editors=0011)

Comment: What is in `movies`? What is its dataType?

Comment: Try this one. `const maxPages = movies ? Math.floor(movies.length / PAGE_SIZE): 0`

Comment: When there are no movies for a given phrase, your api response does not have a `Search` field. Therefore `movies` are undefined.

Comment: @sirius the above doesn't work – could you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

---

--- EDIT ---

I saw your code here, what is happening is that your calling this:

```
const maxPages = Math.floor(movies.length / PAGE_SIZE);
```

But the movies state on first render stills undefined, because your updating function runs after a while and not on first render:

```
const getMovies = (term='marvel') => {
  setLoading(true);
  axios.get(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=cbb48c03&s=${encodeURIComponent(term)}&plot=full`)
    .then(response => {
    setMovies(response.data.Search);
  }).catch(error => {
    setMovies([]);
  }).finally(() => setLoading(false));
}
```

You have to put this maxPages inside an useEffect, putting movies inside the dependecies array. So everytime movies changes it will run this useEffect again.

It will be something like that:

```
const [maxPages, setMaxPages] = useState();
...

useEffect(() => {
 if (!movies) {
  return;
 }

 setMaxPages(Math.floor(movies.length / PAGE_SIZE));
}, [movies])
```

---

This is happening because your const movies is undefined.

You are trying to access the length of something that is undefined, that's why it is giving you this error.

Put a console.log before it so you can see.

Comment: sure, and the result is 0 1 1, could you help please?

Comment: thanks, really helpful. did you try to implement that on my demo? cos it doesn't work on mine. https://codepen.io/davide77/pen/vYZxZWV?editors=0010

Comment: @user173420 Yes, it worked here! You can check on the console. But now you will have to see how you want to use it. I resolved the problem of movies being undefined, but idk what you wanna do with this value.

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/azsidaniel/pen/eYRvRjW?editors=0011

Comment: the search is still broken, if I type I can't search. What I want to do is simply search movies

Comment: So the problem is not with that line of code that you put it here on your question! I suggest that you open another issue or keep investigating what is happening there.

Comment: well the movies.length was the error that I was getting.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Math.ceil property for pagination because it always rounds a number up to the next largest integer.

for example, if you have 7 movies and
you are showing 2 movies per page.

So you need to have 4 pages.

7/2=>Math.ceil(3.5)=>4 pages.